# How to trigger R script from MVC Controller Action method and receive the results into a datatable?

Tags: r, model-view-controller

I have a bar chart to display. 
Currently MVC controller's action method makes call to a stored procedure in SQL and the returned data in data table format is bound to the chart.

what now i wanted to achieve is , consider the data returned from SQL, pass it to R script to do some processing and return the data. I want to bind this data to my chart.

Please assist

Comment: How and where do you "display" the bar chart? What do you mean by "bind this data to my chart"? A [reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/) is always welcome.

Comment: Currently I am using a Kendo UI bar chart and to that chart i and binding data returned from sql proc.  I want to process this data and want to bind the processed data to my chart . Processing needs to happen via R